# Any example of equivalent norms in infinite-dimensional vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I have read in [this paper](//www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/10.4169/000298910x515811.pdf?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) that the number of inequivalent norms in infinit-dimensional space is exactly $2^{dim X}$, In my guess if am true this mean that there are Equivalent norms in infinit dimensional space which I want to know one example of it ? and if there is no Equivalents norms in infinit dimensional vector space just any proof for that ?

Comment: Take a norm $\|\cdot \|$ and $c>0$. The norm $c\|\cdot \|$ is equivalent to $\|\cdot \|$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ is any norm on any vector space $X$, then $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ and $2\lVert\cdot\rVert$ are equivalent norms.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a silly example: define on $X=\mathcal{C}^0([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ the norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ given by $\sup_{x\in [a,b]} f(x)=\lVert f\rVert.$ Define a second norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert'$ by $2\sup_{x\in [a,b]}f(x)=\lVert f\rVert'$. Then indeed we have that there exist constants $c$ and $C$ such that 
$$ c\lVert f\rVert'\le \lVert f\rVert\le C\lVert f\rVert'.$$
For instance, take $c=\frac{1}{2}$ and $C=1$. More generally, if we have a normed space over $\mathbb{R}$, a norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ determines a family of equivalent norms $\lambda \lVert\cdot\rVert$ for $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$. This fact is independent of the dimensionality of the space.